# Convert Java `sort` signature with `? super T` to Scala (generics)

Tags: java, scala, generics

***The problem:***

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430355/translating-generic-%20wildcards-from-java-to-scala) about migrating the Java signature

```
public <A extends Comparable<? super A>> void sort(List<A> list) { }
```

to Scala, there doesn't seem to be a way to avoid a

***`illegal cyclic reference involving type T`***

error if you do a literal translation like this.

```
def compilerFailure[T <: Comparable[_ >: T]](a: Array[T]): T = { }
```

The workaround seems to be to do this instead

```
def workaround[A <: Comparable[U], U >: A](list: List[A]) { }
```

which if you round trip from byte code back to Java, you get this (which looses the `super` part)

```
public <T extends Comparable<U>, U> void scalaToJava(List<U> a) { }
```

***My questions:***

Is the `scalaToJava` version equivalent to the following?

```
public <T extends Comparable<?>> void sort(List<T> a) {
```

I figured when `U` is unbounded, it might as well be `?` or `Object` no?  Then if that's the case, is the Scala `workaround` version equivalent to

```
def sort[A <: Comparable[_]](list: List[A]) { }
```

They all seem to compile for my use case (which is about putting different sub-types in a collection and being able to sort them). ***NB.*** I'm curious about the mechanics and what causes the cyclic reference error and realize that Scala offers better alternatives in terms of covariance etc (ie `Ordering`).

Comment: it should be `def workaround[A <: Comparable[U], U >: A](list: List[A]) { }`. `List[U]` makes no sense here because you would loose any relation to `A`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public <T extends Comparable<?>> void sort(List<T> a)
```

is too general because then you could for instance pass in a `List<A> extends Comparable<Int>` where the compare function would not be applicable to values of type `List<A>`.

You were on the right track with your workaround but made a little mistake. It should be:

```
def workaround[A <: Comparable[A], U >: A](list: List[U]) { }
```

But notice that this is not the way this sort of situation is usually solved in Scala:

See [`scala.math.Ordering`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Ordering).

Comment: Thanks. So to answer my question, you're saying "No" the wildcard Java version? I suspect the Scala compiler is doing more and leaving the type unbounded in the byte code. So comparing byte code/round tripping it may not make sense in this case...